# Build error with QT QRgb

Tags: c++, qt, colors, rgb, build-error

```
QImage source;
QImage dest;
for(unsigned y=0; y<height; ++y)
    {
        for(unsigned x=0; x<width; ++x)
        {
            QColor value = source.color(source.pixelIndex(x, y));   // works fine
            const unsigned r = value.red(), g = value.green(), b = value.blue();
            // some processing
            dest.setColor(dest.pixelIndex(x, y), QRgb(r,g,b));   // build error
        }
    }
```

I get build error on `QRgb(r,g,b)`

```
error: functional cast expression list treated as compound expression
```

I separated other parts of the line so only the `QRgb` fails to build (i had it on separate line to isolate issue)

I am new to qt so I am looking through documentation...

https://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/computing/sepp-irix/qt-2.1.1-to/qcolor.html#24d3b3

https://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/computing/sepp-irix/qt-2.1.1-to/desktop-desktop-cpp.html#qRgb

I am using it exactly like they do, as far as i can tell... I even tried `QRgb(0,0,0)` and it didn't work.

I can't get past this build error, please help

Comment: The documentation you linked to points to Qt 2.1, which is very old.  Are you actually using this version of Qt?  If not, why not use the latest documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/index.html

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I am using Qt 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `QRgb` is not a class or function, but the type name. I cannot use it as a class or function to construct an `QRgb` value. You need to use qRgb global function instead, like:

```
dest.setColor(dest.pixelIndex(x, y), qRgb(r,g,b));
```

Comment: I don't know how I could have missed it ! Thank you, I stared at it for so long !

Comment: You have to use #include <QRgb> directly in your header (because it's indeed a type).